# How to Upgrade the heroku plan to Hobby?

Tags: heroku

I am trying to buy Hobby plan of Heroku but not getting any option to start with.
Can anyone please tell me from where exactly to upgrade the plan

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and I spent almost the whole day trying to solve it. Go to your Heroku dashboard:

1. click on the app you wish to upgrade.
2. click on resources.
3. click on change dyno type
4. select your plan.
5. Save your changes and make sure that you see the cost of your plan display at the bottom of the list of addons you have installed.

If you wish to set the SSl certificate of the application, go click on settings, then configure SLL, select what is best for. If you select Automatic Certificate Management (ACM), notice that it will only create certificates for domains you configure after it has been activated. Meaning that if you already have a custom domain name before activating ACM, the domain name won't have an SSL certificate.

Answer (score 0):

Before upgrading your Dyno you need to deploy your code with file name Procfile on root pointing to web dyno.after 1st deployment you will see Dyno under resources tab.